# Taking input from textField and displaying it in textArea

Tags: java, javafx

I have having trouble getting my program to take the user input from textField and displaying it in textArea. The program I'm making is a Stack/Queue program. It has a textField that a user inputs a number into. Then there is a button that takes the input and displays it in the textArea as a Stack(FILO).

Edit 1: 
I am able to move the user input into the textArea now but, whenever I add a second input it just replaces the old input with the new instead of showing the list. I am supposed to use a toString method to show the whole list? Where do I need to put the toString method if I need it?

TLDR, How do I take input from textField and display it in textArea?

This is my main class.

```
TextField text = new TextField();
TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Text Area");

public class StackQueue extends Application
{
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
{
    Stack myStack = new Stack();

    Button btAdd = new Button("Add");       
    Button btDel = new Button("Delete");
    Button btClear = new Button("Clear");
    BorderPane bpane = new BorderPane();

    text.setPrefWidth(50);
    text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    text.setText("Label");
    text.clear();

    textArea.setPrefColumnCount(1);
    textArea.setPrefRowCount(10);
    textArea.clear();

    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(btAdd, btDel, btClear);
    bpane.setTop(hBox);
    bpane.setCenter(text);
    bpane.setBottom(textArea);

    Scene scene = new Scene(bpane, 500, 250);
    stage.setTitle("Stack Example");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();


    EventHandler<ActionEvent> addEvent = event -> add();
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> delEvent = event -> del();

    btAdd.setOnAction(addEvent);
    btDel.setOnAction(delEvent);




public void add()
{
    textArea.setText(text.getText(x));
}

public void del()
{

}

}



public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    launch(args);
}

}
```

This is the Stack class.

```
public class Stack<E>
{
public String status = "String";

public ArrayList<E> arrayList;


public Stack()
{
    arrayList = new ArrayList(10);
}


public void add(String x)
{
    arrayList.add(0, (E) x);
}

//public String del
{

}

public void Clear()
{

}

}
```

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having?

Comment: I'm trying to get user input to display in textArea. the textArea is an arrayList.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: `text.getText(x)` TextField has no method like this signature!

Comment: *I'm trying to get user input to display in textArea.* Ok, so what problem are you facing? *the textArea is an arrayList.* Wait, what??

Comment: So I am making a a Javafx program to show how a stack works. I am trying to take user input from the textField and display it in the textArea. The stack is stored in an arrayList. The add method in the main program is where I'm having trouble.

Comment: Yet you categorically refuse to say what trouble you're having. Seems strange considering you're asking us for help.

Comment: The add method in the main program gives me an error saying "Syntax error on token "add", AnnotationName expected after this token"

Comment: Your `add` and `del` methods appear to inside your `start` method, which is not valid syntax. (There are many, many other problems, and it's really unclear what you're trying to do, but that's the cause of the compile error you cited.)

Comment: Thank you James_D. I'm trying to make a program that takes user input and displays it as a Stack, so that each new input gets added to the top and when one is removed it comes off the top. When I put the add and del methods outside of start it says they cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have included **add()** and **del()** function inside the start() function. You need to move them outside of start() function and inside of your StackQueue class. 
After doing that the variables **text** and **textArea** should be created outside of start() function because the method add() and del() are trying to get the value of text and textArea variables.

Finally, you should implement the logic to handle addition and deletion of elements inside add() and del() methods.

Paste the following code in StackQueue.java file. I didn't implement the deletion functionality and you need to tweak the add() method too. I hope now you will be able to solve it.

**I added a string which will get the old value of text field and append that old value when further addition is done along with the new value**

```
public class StackQueue extends Application {
            TextField text = new TextField();
            TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    String oldText;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Stack myStack = new Stack();

        Button btAdd = new Button("Add");
        Button btDel = new Button("Delete");
        Button btClear = new Button("Clear");
        BorderPane bpane = new BorderPane();
        text.setPrefWidth(50);
        text.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        text.setText("Label");
        text.clear();
        textArea= new TextArea("Text Area");
        textArea.setPrefColumnCount(1);
        textArea.setPrefRowCount(10);
        textArea.clear();
        oldText = text.getText();
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(btAdd, btDel, btClear);
        bpane.setTop(hBox);
        bpane.setCenter(text);
        bpane.setBottom(textArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bpane, 500, 250);
        stage.setTitle("Stack Example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


        EventHandler<ActionEvent> delEvent = event -> del();

        btAdd.setOnAction( e -> {
                textArea.setText(oldText + text.getText());
                oldText = oldText + text.getText() +"\n";
        });
        btDel.setOnAction(delEvent);

}



    public void del()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I declared the textField and Area in the class like you showed and that fixed it.